# Categorification of Metric Spaces

Tags: category-theory

Let the category $\mathcal{V}$ consist of elements of $\mathbb{R}^+$ ($[0,\infty]$) and give it a  monoidal structure with $+$ as the tensor product and $0$ the identity element.  Let morphisms in $\mathcal{V}$ be 
$\operatorname{Hom(a,b)}=\cases{*\quad a\le b\\ 0\quad a< b}$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{R^+}$.  Now let $\mathcal{C}$ be enriched in $\mathcal{V}$.  You can [show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0p3iS3Nf-fs) that the morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ are $Hom(a,b)\in [0,\infty]$ and that the notions of the triangle inequality and the identity are generalized in $\mathcal{C}$ as
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(a,b)+\operatorname{Hom}(b,c)\ge \operatorname{Hom}(a,c)\quad\text{ and }\quad 0\ge \operatorname{Hom}(a,a)
$$

My question is, since $\mathcal{C}$ is a categorical generalization of $\mathcal{V}$ then $\mathcal{C}$ must encapsulate other categories similar to $\mathcal{V}$.  What are some examples of categories similar to $\mathcal{V}$ that when enriched give $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "since $\mathcal{C}$ is a categorical generalization of $\mathcal{V}$ then $\mathcal{C}$ must encapsulate other categories similar to $\mathcal{V}$".  $\mathcal{C}$ is just some category enriched in $\mathcal{V}$.  It might be empty!

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like I don't understand what an enriched category is in that case.  Perhaps my question should be, what do we gain by enriching categories?

Comment: The main reason that we care about enriched categories is that they are "more structured" versions of categories that show up in practice.  For instance, $Ab$-enriched categories are ubiquitous in algebra (basically, whenever you have an algebraic structure whose morphisms are some kind of "linear maps").

Comment: The main point here - though not answering your question - is that a (small) enriched category over $\mathcal V$ - based on what you have written -  is a *generalized metric space* with $\hom$ giving the distance function, which is not necessarily symmetric, and we might also have $\hom(a,b)=0$ for $a\ne b$.